# Where is cmdline.txt located on the NOOBS SD card?

Tags: noobs, cmdline.txt

I need to reset a forgotten RPI OS password. In order to do that I need to insert the SD card to the computer and edit the cmdline.txt file. It is not anywhere on the SD card root folder or any of the subfolders.

These are the files that I can find on the SD card

- (DIR) defaults
- (DIR) os
- bootcode.bin
- BUILD-DATA
- INSTRUCTIONS-README.txt
- recovery.cmdline
- recovery.elf
- RECOVERY_FILES_DO_NOT_EDIT
- recovery.img
- recovery.rfs
- riscos-boot.bin
- config.txt
- (DIR) etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cmdline.txt` is residing in `/boot` which is a separate FAT partition on the SD card (that's the way with my Arch Linux but to my knowlegde the same for other distributions). If that SD card is read at a Windows PC this should be the only partition directly visible in the explorer.

EDIT: As we are now discussing NOOBS, same rules apply, with just more than one possible `/boot` partition on the card. Other than for RISC OS these partitions will still be VFAT but Windows cannot directly access them. Best way to go: mount with Linux.

---

Note that on NOOBS (from ["NOOBS bootup (low-level)"](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained#noobs-bootup-low-level)):

> When the Raspberry Pi is powered on with a NOOBS card inserted, it:
>
> 1. Loads and runs `bootcode.bin` from the FAT-format /dev/mmcblk0p1,
>      exactly as it does for standalone images. (This behaviour is built
>      into the BCM2835's internal firmware on all Pis, and so can't be
>      changed.)
> 2. `bootcode.bin` then spots that `start.elf` is missing, so it
>      loads and runs `recovery.elf` instead.
> 3. Running `recovery.elf` then
>      switches the firmware into "NOOBS mode" - it uses `recovery.img` instead
>      of `kernel.img`, `recovery.cmdline` instead of `cmdline.txt`, and it sets
>      the root filesystem to `recovery.rfs`.

In case that's not clear, this is why you don't have a `start.elf`, which the normal distros do.  It means that you should use the `recovery.cmdline` file (in your question) instead of `cmdline.txt`

Comment: So you're saying that to access the FAT partition I need to read the SD card on a Linux machine?

Comment: No, no. This partition can be read/written both with linux and windows. The folder you describe in your question is most likely exactly this partition!

Comment: It seems that I'm accessing the NOOBS partition and not the boot partition. The label of the partition is RECOVERY and there is no cmdline.txt to be found anywhere

Comment: Ok, I see. I am not familiar with NOOBs. But https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained sounds pretty interesting. But the `/boot` partition(s) are still FAT and should be able to be accessed?

Comment: Ok, I think that windows will refuse to access multiple partitions on removable drives.

Comment: I've edited some stuff in from the link you posted, I hope that is okay ;) @Prashan This should now explain what you are looking for, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks. I am really not familiar with Noobs and got confused as the question did not specify this in the first place. Thanks to your edit the answer may stay.

Answer (score 3):

Some Raspberry Pi SD cards contain a bug where the wrong partition is mounted as `/boot`.

You probably find that:

- `cmdline.txt` and/or `config.txt` are not present in `/boot`
- changes to these files seem to not take effect

https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained#noobs-os-installation mentions two FAT partitions. The files you list belong to the `RECOVERY` partition (`/dev/mmcblk0p1`), not boot partition (e.g. `/dev/mmcblk0p5`).

As this is a bug that's been fixed, rather than change `/etc/fstab` manually, the simplest option is to update your Raspberry Pi:

```
$ sudo apt-get udate
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

On the bootup of raspberry pi press Shift button , it will take you to recovery mode, there you can see the option Edit Config.

In that you can select cmdline.txt

The original content should look like

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
```

At the end of it add the following text

```
init=/bin/sh
```

Thats it!

You are ready to go,
Hit the ok button !

In the next bootup of Pi You will be asked to enter the new Password

Hope this helps

Comment: Huge security hole?

Answer (score 1):

While booting, press Shift+up and it will take you to the recovery console. the cmdline.txt file is editable from one of the tabs

Answer (score 0):

The `cmdline.txt` file you are looking for is found in `/boot.bak`

the file contents is this:

```
dwc_otg.lmp_enable=0 console-ttyAMAO,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait logo.nologo loglevel=1 quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Akash on Jul 22, 2016 was most useful for me. I did run into something that I wanted to add to what he said, because it seems something has changed with the latest Raspbian update.

After the pi starts booting and you hold shift to enter setup mode, it brings you to a recovery mode GUI. Here you can access the `config.txt` file that is mentioned.

I was not able to get anywhere with adding `init=/bin/sh` to the end of the file. When I did, the boot would hang.

I had read on some other sites that people were instead adding `single` to the end of the file. I tried that and it worked. This time, when it booted, it ended up at a command line (instead of booting into Pixel). From there I did:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and was able to get back to the configuration screen to change my password again.

How I messed up the password is still a mystery, but I think it had to do with using the numeric keypad while typing the password at the command line and it may have had NumLock disabled...

Hope this helps somebody (it'll probably be my future self).

Comment: I am not certain that the, now default, `systemd` still allows you to start up a single bash shell instead of the normal system - it may be that the _maintenance_ or _single_ mode startup is only applicable to a system with a sysV `init` configured {_my Desktop Debian PC for instance is configured for a dual-init but I never allow `systemd` to boot - hell I do not even know if it would properly and on that `grub` actually fills out the `init=` with `/lib/sysvinit/init` or `/lib/systemd/systemd` as required - so you can see how dropping in `/bin/sh` might work there_}.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.  Hold shift to open recovery mode on bootup. Hit the edit config, then click on cmdline.txt. Add word single to end.  Hit exit. On bootup, will stop at root command line.  enter sudo raspi-config.  Select second option, change user passwd. Then, finish and halt system. Re-boot then hold shift again.  Delete word 'single' from cmdline.txt and boot system. login with updated password.